# Index core names and rebuild core

Tags: solr, configuration

I've noticed in Sitecore 9 (at least through 9.1.1) that the value of `<param desc="core>` is based on the prefix you use during installation (IE, if you chose "local" as a prefix, the core is called "local_master_index"). This is then written into the config files in `App_Config/Include/Sitecore/ContentSearch` for you.

I'm trying to set up a foundation layer config to auto-register a rebuild core for the master/web indexes. My default approach to this has been to use `<param desc="rebuildcore" patch:after="*[@desc='core']">$(id)_rebuild</param>`, but it occurs to me this is technically incorrect if you just copy the cores on Solr and append "_rebuild" to them as many documents suggest...in my example, the rebuild core on Solr is `local_master_index_rebuild`, but Sitecore will be looking for `sitecore_master_index_rebuild`.

I know it's as easy as using the ID name for the rebuild core on Solr, but I was wondering if there was a programmatic way to take the value from the "core" param and apply it to the "rebuildcore" param on the fly, like you use `$(id)` as a replacement value?